# Constraint view to the top of tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have problem with positioning the view at the very top of table view. I have UITableViewController inside the UINavigatonController. I add subview to it's view. I want the subview to be always at the top of the screen, at the same place where navigation bar is. If I setup top constraint which pins the top of the subview to the top of tableView, than it appears under the navigation bar, not at the very top of the screen. How to solve this problem? Here is the code and the picture:

```
@interface ViewController : UITableViewController
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView* redSquare = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    redSquare.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:redSquare];
    [redSquare setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [redSquare.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.topAnchor].active = YES;
    [redSquare.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:100].active = YES;
    [redSquare.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:100].active = YES;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* reuseIdentifier = @"ri";
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    }
    return cell;
}


@end
```

[image]

Comment: Where exactly do you want it? It went where you told it to go.

Comment: do you want the view to be moved with table scroll ? Did u look into table view header view property ?

Comment: @jervine10 I expect redSquare to be behind navigation bar. View Hierarchy Debugger shows that tableView is fullscreen, so as I understand it it's top is at the very top of the screen.

Comment: @Mr.T I don't want it to move with tableView. Ideally I would pin it to the top of navigation bar, but it's not possible, because it's not in my view hierarchy.